# Changing the value of enqueued Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to change the value of a value of a variable, which is located within the the enqueued javascript file.

Here is my code:

**- Enqueued Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#adminSearch").click(function() {

    var adminURL = "";
    window.location = adminURL;

    });
});
```

**- Javascript on the Wordpress page:**

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var adminURL = "test.org/shop";
  });
</script>
```

The reason I am trying to do this, is I am trying to create a function, where I can replace the url with a value assigned by the variable "adminURL" and change it's value on different Wordpress pages.

This would help make the code modular and I can use it throughout the website.

Any suggestions would be a major help!

Thanks :)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Since you're declaring `var adminURL` within your enqueued file, that variable's scope is limited to the anonymous function it's within. You'll need to make it global (or better yet, refactor your code to allow for better communication without using globals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quite understand why you need to do this, I think refactoring might be better but you could try using data attributes.

```
jQuery("#adminSearch").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var adminURL = $(this).data('adminurl');
    window.location = adminURL;
)};
```

So you'd get the url from a data attribute on the clicked link itself instead of an attribute.

```
<a href="#" id="adminSearch" data-adminurl="http://test.org/shop">
```

This code has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks you were right, I revisited my code and refactored it. Now it works well thank you! :)